# WCF Service Call Failing Due To Too Much Data Being Passed?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, web-services, endpoint

I've got a WCF service that I've written in C# which passes to the caller (a C# WPF application) a collection of instantiated objects.  Works great, however if the collection I'm returning has too many objects, the call fails on the client side after about 10 seconds with a generic exception (which itself contains a series of generic inner exceptions).  Here is the exception and inner exceptions:

> {"An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://myserver/MyAppService/MyAppService.svc. This could be due to
>   the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could
>   also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
>   (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more
>   details."}
>   {"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."}
>   {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}
>   {"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"}

The issue is 100% reproduceable and is definitely related to the size of the collection, and not the content. I know this because if I break up the single collection in to multiple smaller collections and pass those back one at a time, it works fine. Only when they're all together and the collection is to large is it a problem.

I tried increasing the `maxReceivedMessageSize` property on the client side's `app.config` file to 2147483647 but the error still persists. Also tried increasing the timeout period, but no affect. Here are the properties in the `app.config` file. I've tried increasing pretty much every number below to 2147483647 and tried changing `maxBufferPoolSize` to 0, but no luck:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_iMyAppService" 
         closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" 
         receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas 
           maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
           maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
           maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_iMyAppService" 
         closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" 
         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
         allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas 
           maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
           maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint name="CurrencyConvertorSoap" 
      address="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="CurrencyConvertorSoap"
      contract="CurrencyConverterService.CurrencyConvertorSoap" />

  <endpoint name="CurrencyConvertorSoap12" 
      address="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"
      binding="customBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="CurrencyConvertorSoap12"
      contract="CurrencyConverterService.CurrencyConvertorSoap" />

  <endpoint name="WSHttpBinding_iMyAppService"
      address="http://myserver/MyAppService/MyAppService.svc"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_iMyAppService"
      contract="MyAppService.iMyAppService" >
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>

  <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_iMyAppService" 
      address="http://myserver/MyAppService/MyAppService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_iMyAppService"
      contract="MyAppService.iMyAppService" />
</client>
```

What else could I change or add to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be maxitemsinobjectgraph. Enable the wcf trace, you should see a stack trace in there.

Comment: Darn...I was really hopeful that would be it when I read your response, but no go unfortunately.  Unless if I didn't do it right.  But I added this to my app.config:  <behaviors> 
    <endpointBehaviors> 
        <behavior name="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior"> 
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" /> 
        </behavior> 
    </endpointBehaviors> 
</behaviors>   and then this to my endpoint line:  behaviorConfiguration="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior"  But again...didn't work unfortunately.  Same error.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I'm not at my PC but I'm pretty sure you need to make the settings on the host *and* the client? Did you try that (this would be the same for @felan's setting).

Comment: I tried Felan's suggestion, but that didn't fix it unfortunately.  I  tried adding the behavior for maxitemsinobjectgraph to the server side web.config, but that didn't do it.  I couldn't add Felan's to the server side though because the web.config didn't have those options anywhere so I wasn't sure where to put it.

Comment: Got Felan's on the server side too by following examples.  Still get the error though.

Comment: Got it...Finally.  The problem was that on the server-side web.config, the behavior maxItemsInObjectGraph had to be a servicebehavior, not an endpoint behavior as I had it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I recall I've had to increase maxArrayLength up before in similiar sounding situation.

Comment: I tried increasing it up to 2147483647, but got the same error.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: You may also have to increase maxStringContentLength="8192" and I wouldn't make maxArrayLength that big.

Comment: Tried...no go unfortunately.  Thanks though.